# When I type 'git branch' nothing happens

Tags: git

So far, I have cloned an empty git repo, and created a new branch with 'git checkout -b branchname'. My understanding is that typing 'git branch' should now give me some output like

```
* mybranch
  master
```

Instead, I get no output at all. 
However, entering 'git status' still tells me

```
# On branch branchname
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

So why don't I get any output from 'git branch'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any `git -b` command. Did you mean `git checkout -b branchname` (which creates the branch and switches to it)?

You can create a branch doing `git branch branchname`.

Also, you can use `git branch -a` which list the remote branches also.

**EDIT:**
By the way. If you have no commit (Just saw your "#Initial commit"), you do not have any branch (not even master). You must make your first commit first.

Comment: Fixed the typo. git checkout -b branchname was what I did.